# Android studio image spawn

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create an app that has balls falling from the top of the screen down . The balls are different colors . How can I make the computer randomly choose which ball to send down ? Also can I change the speed and how many fall at once ? How do I make walls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two balls in an array. Suppose if you have a Ball class, put them in a Ball array then select a random number to choose which ball you want to fall from the sky.
Like this:

```
Ball[] ballArray = {ball1, ball2};
int randomBall;

//Loop to randomly throw ballls from sky
randomBall = (int) Math.random()*2; //Choose between ball at index 0 or 1.
```

And yes, in programming you can do anything. I don't know your code so I don't know how to implement the speed for you. And yes you can throw both balls at once.